# List Cognito Users in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to list all cognito users from my Cognito AWS service, I am trying to get the users pool id and I am taking it from here (please mind following image attached):
[image]

as I am using the following code (and taking the Pool Id from the image above):

```
public class AwsClient {
    private AWSCognitoIdentityProvider identityProvider;
    private final static String AWS_USER_POOL_ID = "<USER_POOL_ID>";

    public AwsClient(String regionName){
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")));

        this.identityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider)
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        ListUsersRequest req = new ListUsersRequest();
        req = req.withUserPoolId(AWS_USER_POOL_ID);
        ListUsersResult response = identityProvider.listUsers(req);

    }
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
User pool us-east-1_qvWp8iA5f does not exist.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What does `aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --region us-east-1 --max-results 10` return? And do the credentials used by the SDK have permission for cognito?

Comment: ensure that your in the correct Region

Comment: @DraganVelkovski I am in the correct region.

Comment: I feel you title does not properly represent your problem. Perhaps adding the error message might help attract people with knowledge. Idea: `AWS Cognito list users: User pool does not exist`.